# SharedSizeGroup to different Grid in different parent control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, sharedsizegroup

So, I have 3 user controls :

**1. SectionV.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="NumberedMusicalScoresWriter.V.SectionV"...>
...
    <Grid Background="{Binding BackgroundColor, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        ...
        <V:BarV Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" DataContext="{Binding GClefBarVM, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <V:BarV Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" DataContext="{Binding FClefBarVM, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Grid>
...
```

**2. BarV.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="NumberedMusicalScoresWriter.V.BarV"...>
...
    <Grid Background="{Binding BackgroundColor, Mode=OneWay}">
        ...
        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding NotationGroupVMs, Mode=OneWay}">
            ...
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <V:NotationGroupV/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
...
```

**3. NotationGroupV.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="NumberedMusicalScoresWriter.V.NotationGroupV"...>
...
    <Grid Background="{Binding BackgroundColor, Mode=OneWay}">
        ...
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Mid"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        ...
    </Grid>
...
```

As you have figured, `NotationGroupV` is a collection of `UserControl` in `BarV`, and `BarV` is owned by `SectionV` as a two of. (`SectionV` is also used as a collection member of its parent control)

The issue is on the center row height of `NotationGroupV`, which has `SharedSizeGroup="Mid"`. I want to share it to fellow `NotationGroupV` in the apps.

So, basically, I want to share `SharedSizeGroup` to other `NotationGroupV` in different parents.

Anyone know how to expose `SharedSizeGroup` this way?

(Please ask anything to clarify)

Thank you.

P.S. In this [link](http://wpf.2000things.com/2011/11/08/425-sharedsizegroup-allows-sharing-column-sizes-across-different-grids/), it's explained how to share them in a different grid, BUT in the same xaml.

Comment: While I can't confirm for sure that your requirement will work, I can confirm that as long as you set the `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` Attached Property to `True` on a parent container control of *both* of the `Grid`s that you have set up `SharedSizeGroup`s for, then it *should* work. To find out for sure, just try it out... you could have probably tested it yourself quicker than the time it took you to write this question.

Comment: @Sheridan thanks for your reply. But the parent container doesn't have such grid. NotationGroupV, which have such grid, is only owned by BarV, which owned by parent control. So, it's only NotationGroupV which have SharedSizeScope="Mid". I've tried it before, just I'm not sure the "tried" you and I meant are the same. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: You should be able to set `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` on *any common ancestor* of the different grids; they don't have to be in the same file, as the property is evaluated at runtime.  Do the grids not share a common ancestor (parent control)?

Comment: @MikeStrobel the grid I wanna to share is also `NotationGroupV`.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said *parent container* and not *parent `Grid`*. If there is no parent container control, just add one.... (put everything into it).

Comment: @Sheridan pls check out my updated first post. Is that what you meant? If yes, it doesn't work either.

Comment: You're only supposed to set `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` to `True` on one single parent container control.

Comment: @Sheridan oooh, I misinterpret your comment. It works now thanks. You wanna put it in answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I can't confirm for sure that your requirement will work, I can confirm that as long as you set the `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` Attached Property to `True` on a parent container control of *both* of the `Grid`s that you have set up `SharedSizeGroup`s for, then it *should* work. To find out for sure, just try it out... you could have probably tested it yourself quicker than the time it took you to write this question.

If there is no parent container control at the moment, just add one.... (put everything into it).
The important thing to note here is that you're only supposed to set `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` to `True` on the one single parent container control and not on every `Grid`.